# netfilter-persistent restart after reboot

Tags: debian, iptables

I need to run:

```
sudo service netfilter-persistent restart
```

after I reboot my server, in order for port `25` to be opened. I would like to automate this. How should I configure this?

I already tried:

```
sudo systemctl enable netfilter-persistent
```

but that didn't help. I'm running Debian 9.

Answer (score 1):

`netfilter-persistent` may not be having the desired effect you intend without carrying out a save.

Normally `iptables-save` will suffice but if that's not working you can write the rules directly via the following. `iptables-save >/etc/iptables/rules.v4`

This should provide you with the desired outcome of having port 25 open on boot

With regards to your initial question.

`systemctl enable netfilter-persistent` would all that's required to enable the service.

You have not specified the status of the service if it's running or not post boot.

If you can please check `systemctl status netfilter-persistent` post boot to confirm it is actually running vs failed etc.

Passing disable , then enable can resolve some issues with bad hooks.

Comment: When running sudo journalctl -e -u netfilter-persistent.service after reboot, I get:

netfilter-persistent[1722]: run-parts: /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/25-ip6tables exited with return code 2
systemd[1]: netfilter-persistent.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: Failed to start netfilter persistent configuration.
systemd[1]: netfilter-persistent.service: Unit entered failed state.

Comment: I think this is my problem:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=867560
After reboot it fails, but manually restarting works.

Comment: Write the answer if you've solved your issue, please.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file '`/etc/iptables/rules.v4`'. It's your firewall rule set. May be you have other script, that overwrite the firewall configuration. Investigate the startup scripts. Also, if you use the ipset, it also can affect to the rules loading.